# Regions conjunction - for what reason are there so many vertices?

Tags: plotting, regions

I try to plot the intersection of some regions but `RegionPlot` does something weird: conjunction doesn't actually match the area:

```
RegionPlot[{14 - 4 x1 >= 0, 17 - 10 x1 + 7 x2 <= 0,
14 - 4 x1 >= 0 && 17 - 10 x1 + 7 x2 <= 0}, {x1, -4, 4}, {x2, 1, 4}]
```

[image: plot1]

And it depends on x1 range, e.g. it looks pretty good for x1=0..6 with the same functions:
[image: plot2]

The more regions the worse graph:

```
RegionPlot[{x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0, 20 - 8 x1 + 3 x2 >= 0,
14 - 4 x1 >= 0, 17 - 10 x1 + 7 x2 <= 0}, {x1, -5, 4}, {x2, -5, 4}]
RegionPlot[{x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0 && 20 - 8 x1 + 3 x2 >= 0 &&
14 - 4 x1 >= 0 && 17 - 10 x1 + 7 x2 <= 0}, {x1, -5, 4}, {x2, -5, 4}]
```

[image: plot3]

How to fix this?

*Extra question: can I draw just straight line, not a region, over other regions on `RegionPlot`? Equality in 1st argument draws nothing.*

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 100`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you, post your answer

Comment: Or use the option `MaxRecursion -> 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:  `PlotPoints -> 100`